# TypeError: html.indexOf is not a function with ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I get TypeError with ng-bind-html. I have no idea whats the problem. I have current version of  "angular-sanitize": "1.2.20". Any suggestions would really help.

```
.filter('filterLocation', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
return function (visit) {
  var displayLocation = "";
  if (visit != null  && visit !== 'NOT PROVIDED') {
    displayLocation = visit;
  }
  // return the location information in the correct format.
  return displayLocation;

};
```

This is my html which uses filter

```
    <td name="location" ng-bind-html="visit | filterLocation"></td>
```

Comment: What if `visit === undefined`? The error message in your question title suggests that `html` is supposed to be a string, but isn't when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You sould add a 3 brackets at the end of your function :

```
.filter('filterLocation', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
return function (visit) {
  var displayLocation = "";
  if (visit != null  && visit !== 'NOT PROVIDED') {
    displayLocation = visit;
  }
  // return the location information in the correct format.
  return displayLocation;

}
}]);
```

If this is not your issue, **juste make sure that you use the same version between angular.min.js and angular-sanitize.js**.

for example the 1.2.15 version:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```